# No targets. Stop. error when installing emqttd

Tags: installation, target

I'm trying to install `emqttd` on my Raspberry Pi but am faced with the following error.

When I do `cd emqttd && make && make dist` I get this error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/emqttd/deps/gproc'
make[1]: *** No targets.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/emqttd/deps/gproc'
erlang.mk:310: recipe for target 'deps' failed
make: *** [deps] Error 2
```

I need help to solve the problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wget
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev
wget http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_19.2.tar.gz
tar -xzvf otp_src_19.2.tar.gz
cd otp_src_19.2/
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..
rm otp_src_19.2.tar.gz
sudo rm -R otp_src_19.2/

git clone https://github.com/emqtt/emq-relx.git
cd emq-relx && make
cd _rel/emqttd && ./bin/emqttd console
```